# Comparing GIS libraries

Tags: geoprocessing, mapnik, saga

I am new to GIS. As a part of my research, I want to figure out among OSSIM, Saga API, Terralib and Mapnik which one will best satisfy the following functionalities and why (all for desktop GIS application).

- Loading/Saving major GIS files (library OGR/GDAL)
- Database compatibility.
- Vectorial element linked to a field of the database
- Georeferencing.
- Zooming, panning
- Multiple vector Layers
- Performances (loading of large shapefile, quick zoom, quick panning, tile support, etc)
- User defined symbol
- Zone selection (polygon, circle, square, etc.)
- Animations
- OGC compatibility

Also which all can be used with Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial list of programs seems very strange. Among others you miss qgis,gvsig and grass, which are the programs I would first look at.

Mapnik is not suitable. ossim is not geared towards vector data. Saga GIS has a very good performancem and tools for vector analysis, but it is geared towards 'automated' analysis, with little interaction, so it depends what you want to do.

An overview of different gis programs can be found here:
http://www.spatialserver.net/osgis/Desktopgis_overview.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My initial list is all LGPL C++ libraries that can be used for building a new desktop GIS application. "Saga geared towards 'automated' analysis with little interaction", is that about the SAGA API or the SAGA GUI? What about Terralib?

Comment: I have no experience using terralib, but it seems to be suitable for what you need. If you are specifically looking for libraries, also look to fdo. http://fdo.osgeo.org/

Comment: Thanks for replying back. You are right I am searching for libraries. I have one more doubt. Do FDO provide funtionalities written by me above like Georeferencing, user defined symbol, etc..? I am finding it difficult to understand whether FDO provides the functionalities by reading the website.

Comment: Update to the previous question. About the comment about SAGA "Saga geared towards 'automated' analysis with little interaction" - Can I assum that it is about SAGA API?

Comment: An api is per definition limited to automated analysis. The comments refer to the gui. SAGA has tools for georeferencing and access to wms/gdal/..., but it are modules: most likely they have a GPL license. If you really want to create a new application with little effort, I think geotools (java) is your best bet: http://geotools.org/. Anyway, I don't understand the need for another gis desktop application, and if your knowledge and research is so little that you have to ask whether some of your proposed libraries are suitable, I'm sure the project is doomed to fail.

Comment: Put differently: why do you want a new application, what do you want to do with it, and why do you limit yourself to the LGPL. Concerning geotools, although it is LGPL, it needs Java advanced imaging (JAI) for much of its functionality, and that library is not LGPL compatible, and certainly not 'free'.

Comment: This is concerning a commercial project and C++ is a prerequisite.

Comment: Please update your original question to reflect these wishes.